# My ggplot in shiny app won't display the values from data table, just displays a single point

Tags: r, shiny

Ok soI am sure this is some little obvious thing that I have missed, but I am new to both R and creating shiny apps, but am trying to teach myself both of them.

I have a data table of RNA values (>20,000 genes from around 150 donors), and I am trying to create a simple shiny app to take 2 genes from the list, and display a scatter plot of the expression values from all 150 donors against each other. Later on I want to do much more with the data, but I am struggling to just get this simple bit running first!

The code below is the current simple state of my app. it is still very simple, but the resultant graph just displays a single point for each gene, image below the code. When what I want it to display is a scatter plot of the relative values in the table

A truncated version of the dataset (that still produces the same error) is also below, along with `str()` results.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
GeneNames <- colnames(Short_cortex5)
ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         selectizeInput(inputId = "gene_X",
                     label = "Select gene X:",
                     choices = GeneNames),

         selectizeInput(inputId = "gene_Y",
                        label = "Select gene Y:",
                        choices = GeneNames)
      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput(outputId = "corrPlot")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$corrPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = Short_cortex5, aes(x=input$gene_X, y=input$gene_Y)) +
      geom_point()
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

```
> str(Short_cortex5)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ MARC2 : num  15.3 16.1 17.3 11.4 21.8 ...
 $ MARCH1: num  2.5 4.7 2.46 3.11 6.12 ...
 $ SEPT1 : num  1.068 0.298 0.381 0.555 0.756 ...
 $ DEC1  : num  0.0261 0 0 0.0226 0 ...
 $ MARCH2: num  81.2 68.9 63.4 84.5 88.5 ...
 $ SEPT2 : num  66.1 89 65.2 49 106.2 ...
 $ MARCH3: num  1.756 1.348 1.25 0.451 2.137 ...
 $ SEPT3 : num  103 208 190 202 223 ...
> Short_cortex5
  MARC2 MARCH1  SEPT1    DEC1 MARCH2  SEPT2 MARCH3 SEPT3
1 15.30  2.501 1.0680 0.02610  81.15  66.14 1.7560 103.3
2 16.07  4.700 0.2980 0.00000  68.90  88.95 1.3480 207.7
3 17.27  2.462 0.3812 0.00000  63.41  65.20 1.2500 190.5
4 11.37  3.107 0.5550 0.02261  84.53  48.98 0.4507 201.9
5 21.76  6.123 0.7558 0.00000  88.49 106.20 2.1370 223.0
6 15.55  4.239 0.5859 0.03581  58.91  69.80 0.5515 214.1
7 16.74  4.596 0.6551 0.02627  70.38  68.50 0.8489 224.4
8 11.48  2.167 0.3567 0.01090  60.14  74.04 1.1210 164.9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you need to change from standard `aes` to `aes_string` in you ggplot call like this

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$corrPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = Short_cortex5, aes_string(x=input$gene_X, y=input$gene_Y)) +
      geom_point()
   })
}
```

this is because the values of the inputs are character vectors

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I knew it would be something incredibly simple like this that I was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

All your app is currently doing is plotting the gene NAMEs against each other, hence you are only getting one point.

You want to tell R to use the variable that corresponds to that name and plot that. The easiest way is to use `Non-standard evaluation` as follows:

```
require(rlang)

output$corrPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = Short_cortex5, aes(x=!!sym(input$gene_X), y=!!sym(input$gene_Y))) +
      geom_point()
  })
```

**Edit:**

Based on the other responses this may not be the easiest way as I claimed!

I suppose it is worth noting from the [release notes](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v3.0.0) of `ggplot2 V3.0.0` that:

> aes() now supports quasiquotation so that you can use !!, !!!,  and
>   :=. This replaces aes_() and aes_string() which are now 
>   soft-deprecated (but will remain around for a long time).

Comment: Thanks, I suppose it is definitely worth noting if I am using depreciated terms, even if they still work for now. Since have only started learning in the last few weeks, I suppose it makes sense learning the new notation now rather than later!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `get` its very generic and not specific to `ggplot` and can be used for other charts and tables you might have

```
  output$corrPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=get(input$gene_X), y=get(input$gene_Y))) +
      geom_point()
  })
```

Comment: This also works perfectly as well, but I think Bertil's suggestion is simpler. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, as long as you aware you can use `get` to access the object by name then its fine, as it will come in handy in other parts of your app

Comment: @PorkChop I sent you a msg on instagram. Would you mind checking? Thank you